# How to write model output to the csv in python in loop

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, model, export-to-excel

I am running a pool of models on a dataset, I want to write the output of multiple models into a csv file:

here is my code:

```
classifiers = [
               ['ExtraTreesClassifier :', ExtraTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=2, random_state = 2)],
                ['LGBMClassifier : ', LGBMClassifier(n_estimators = 400, max_depth=15,learning_rate=1)],
                ['XGB :', XGBClassifier(tree_method = "hist", random_state= 2, learning_rate= 1)],
                ['Random Forest : ', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 400,min_samples_split=2, random_state = 2)],
                ['CatBoost :', CatBoostClassifier(random_seed=22, learning_rate=1)],

]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('top pros.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for name ,classifier in classifiers:

    print(name)
    Model = classifier
    Model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    x_predrf = Model.predict(X_train)
    y_predrf = Model.predict(X_test)

    print(f'Accuracy Test  : {accuracy_score(y_test, y_predrf):0.4f}')
    print(f'Precision Test : {precision_score(y_test, y_predrf):0.4f}')
    print(f'Recall Test    : {recall_score(y_test, y_predrf):0.4f}')
    print(f'Cohen Kappa    : {cohen_kappa_score(y_test, y_predrf):0.4f}; || AUC:{roc_auc_score(y_test,y_predrf):0.4f}')

    print(pd.crosstab(y_test, y_predrf, margins = True))
    print(classification_report(y_test,y_predrf))

    importances = Model.feature_importances_
    weights = pd.Series(importances, index=X.columns.values).sort_values(ascending=False)
    print(weights.index[:5].to_list())

    weights[:5].to_excel(writer,sheet_name= 'S' + str(name[:-3]))
    writer.save()


    print('------------------------------- END   ----------------------')
```

The output will be an excel file which contains :
Accuracy, Precesion, recall, kappa, classification_report and top5 features for each of the models in a singlesheet based on columns, e.g. first 10 columns contain data of 1st model, 3 blank columns then data of 2nd model and so on.

I am stuck on the code and dont know how to write the output.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

f = open("your_file.csv", "a", newLine="")
tuple = ("output text", 123, "etc...")
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(tuple)
f.close()
```

Try this, replace the place holders with your data, and maybe use a loop.